# Two different type date compare, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I want to compare below two dates,

```
publicationDate contains Timestamp('2018-05-25 00:00:00')

Type: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

publicationDate getting from API Ressult:

```
publicationDate = pd.to_datetime(Json_Data_1['publicationDate'])

datetime.date.today() returns datetime.date(2019, 3, 4)

Type: datetime.date


if 'W' in Frequency:
    while(publicationDate < datetime.date.today()):
        publicationDate = publicationDate + relativedelta(weeks=+1)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an honest mistake.

It looks like you are trying to compare similar things, but you are not.
One is a TS which includes time information, the other one is a data object, which contains only date information.

`datetime.date.today() returns datetime.date(2019, 3, 4)`

if you change your code to:

```
if 'W' in Frequency:
    while(publicationDate < pd.to_datetime(datetime.date.today())):
        publicationDate = publicationDate + relativedelta(weeks=+1)
```

or to:

```
if 'W' in Frequency:
    while(publicationDate.date() < datetime.date.today()):
        publicationDate = publicationDate + relativedelta(weeks=+1)
```

it should work!

hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use [to_pydatetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html#pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime)   in order to convert Timestamp to python datetime